# FBX Export parented objects are missing

Tags: export, parent, .fbx

I have a Problem with the 7.4 binary FBX Export from blender that when I Import my FBX File in Unity or Substance  that some objects what are parented are missing.

When I unparent them and Export this all is fine.

Also when I use the ASCII 6.1 FBX Export all is fine.

What I also done so far recalculate normals & Apply transform, Rotation & Scale to the Objects where i have Problems with.

---

Ok i could definitely reproduce this behavior in the Screenshot below you can see the small "Testscene" that I have done. When I now Export this then the small Cube is not shown in Unity or Substance.

[image: test scene in blender]